# A possible bug with Netbeans, it's executing the old code I changed

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have been coding in a project with over 500 class. One of the classes is responsible for retreiving data from the disk. For some reasons I changed the code, but still, when I run the code, it executes the old code of the class. When I debug, the debugger moves over empty lines which means it still runs over the old code that I have changed. I cleaned and built the project several times. I hand deleted all the .class files and built the project again and nothing changed.

What drives me crazy, is that I copy-paste this code to a new class in a new project and I test it using a main method within the class it works just fine.

I guess it's a bug in netbeans or there is something behind that i don't know about. The version I'm using is 7.1 and it's up to date.

Any idea of how to overcome this ?

Comment: Is the old code in a jar that is on your classpath?

Comment: @JohnPickup I made sure to delete dist and build paths are deleted by myself. Nothing happend and the same problem remained. I also tried deleting the cache of netbeans and the problem is still killing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had some (different) issues because of the cache.  Everything worked after I erased it.

On my machine (Windows 7) it's at: `MyDirectory > .netbeans > 7.0 > var > cache`.

Comment: This is the most common source of problems in netbeans, imho. Usually after a simple cache cleaning everything runs fine.

Comment: @toto2 I deleted the cache, the problem still wasn't changed. I even deleted the var folder itself and nothing changed. Any other ideas ?

Comment: @M-T-A maybe take a look in the cache and make sure that is really where the files for your project are kept.  Maybe there is another cache elsewhere.  Also maybe restart Netbeans after you erase the cache, but I guess you already did that; also erase the build/ at the same time.

Comment: Okay, it worked now. I just uninstalled netbeans, removed .netbeans directory and installed a fresh one. Thanks for follow up :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, this kind of thing happens in eclipse too. Some times when the project is large the build may not work correctly based on the directory structure used in the project. when you say that you are cleaning and rebuilding the code, have you tried to actually go and delete the `bin` folder or the `build` folder? it you do this, i think you should not face the problem again. some times some classes which are no longer referenced might be left in the jars. It could even happen that your old class is still in the classpath from where you run the code(the jars of the old code could still be in your classpath).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

it is not really the cache problem. If you are working with netbeans :

1. Right click on the project
2. Navigate to properties and click it
3. Click on the run circle(button)
4. change the main class to your preferred main class
5. Click ok
   It should work now