# Netbeans keeps running old code, doesn't update to new code

Tags: caching, netbeans

My Netbeans IDE keeps running old code. For example, even after commenting out a particular javascript alert message, the alert message is printed to the screen when I run the application.

I deleted the netbeans cache and restarted netbeans. Still, the same old code is run.

WHAT IS GOING ON HERE ??!!!!!

Comment: How're you commenting your JS code? Using `//` or `/*...*/`?

Comment: //

(as I did before when everything worked fine)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans 7.1 running old codes rather than new ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636423/netbeans-7-1-running-old-codes-rather-than-new-ones)

Comment: [Netbeans runs old code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781930/netbeans-runs-old-code). [A possible bug with Netbeans, it's executing the old code I changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926483/a-possible-bug-with-netbeans-its-executing-the-old-code-i-changed).

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl + F5` on your browser window or manually deleting browser history and cache?

Comment: @Shashanth: I'm using mac ... what am I supposed to enter on mac?

Comment: Check [this](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=15153) link. Sorry, I don't use Mac.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your suggestion, I thought it was for netbeans ... I had done that already ... I even deleted the cache of netbeans

Comment: If it is Java Web App open file explorer and goto your project folder and there you find `build` and `dist` folders just delete that. Alternately you can clean and build the project by right clicking on your project folder inside Netbeans. So, this would delete the old cache of your project.

Comment: also tried that .... sometimes it works now and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: Did you solve this? If so, how?